# ThingsBoard: Custom Widgets JQuery Conflicts Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, thingsboard

I am trying to add 2 custom widgets (a vertical slider and a round slider) onto the same dashboard on ThingsBoard. However, only the round slider widget can display when both are added onto the same dashboard.
The vertical slider gives error: `Widget Error: TypeError: $x(…) is not a function.`

The widgets are created as follows:
**Vertical Slider**
External JavaScript resources:

- https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.js
- https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js
- https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/css/jquery-ui.min.css

JavaScript code:

```
var $x=jQuery.noConflict();
console.log(jQuery.fn.jquery);

$x("#vertSlider").slider();
```

**Round Slider**
External JavaScript resources:

- https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js
- https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/roundSlider/1.6.1/roundslider.min.js
- https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/roundSlider/1.6.1/roundslider.min.css

JavaScript code:

```
var $y=jQuery.noConflict();
console.log(jQuery.fn.jquery);

$y("#slider").roundSlider();
```

Console.log only prints 1.11.3.
Any solutions to solve this problem so that both widgets will be able to work on the same dashboard?

Comment: A workaround which resolved the conflict was to find a JQuery version that supports both sliders. So currently, both are using JQuery version 1.12.4.